# How to select origin ip for X-Forwarded-For field using log parser studio?

Tags: logging, iis, ip, logparser, x-forwarded-for

I am trying to write a query that gets the first value of the X-Forwarded-For field. There is multiple IPs in that field due to load balancers. Is there any way just to get the first value, which is the origin IP? I've looked into information on this and haven't found any.

I am using Log Parser Studio but using the command line version is also an option. This is what I have:

`select X-Forwarded-For, count(X-Forwarded-For) as requestcount from '[LOGFILEPATH]' where cs-uri-stem like '%/%' group by X-Forwarded-For order by count(X-Forwarded-For) desc`

Comment: Can you post an example of the field value - both as it appears in the log, and how it is extracted by LogParser in the X-Forwarded-For field?

Comment: Thanks for answering. What I'm looking for is a way to select the first IP in the X-Forwarded-For field. In the IIS logs, X-Forwarded-For has multiple IPs due to proxies and load balancers. Ex: `127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3`. So I would like to select just the first IP, `127.0.0.1` as that is the origin IP.

Comment: Are you saying that for each log line, LogParser returns `127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3` for that field value? if so, just use `EXTRACT_TOKEN(X-Forwarded-For, 0, '.')` in your `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

you could try below query:

```
select X-Forwarded-For, count(X-Forwarded-For), MAX(DATE) as requestcount from '[LogFilePath]' group by X-Forwarded-For order by MAX(DATE) desc
```

Comment: The query should select the first IP in the X-Forwarded-For field, I don't think this does that

Comment: @techguy1029 this is the result for the select c-ip from the log [image](https://i.imgur.com/meSugKj.png) . try this query `SELECT TOP 1 c-ip, count(c-ip), MAX(DATE) as requestcount from '[LogFilePath]' group by c-ip order by MAX(DATE) desc` replace c-ip with X-Forwarded-For.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What I'm looking for is a way to select the first IP in the X-Forwarded-For field. In the IIS logs, X-Forwarded-For has multiple IPs due to proxies and load balancers. Ex: `127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3`. So I would like to select just the first IP as that is the origin IP.

Answer (score 0):

`logparser -i:W3C "select EXTRACT_TOKEN(x-forwarded-for,0,','), count(x-forwarded-for) FROM d:\tmp\U_ex201202_x.log where sc-status=200 GROUP BY EXTRACT_TOKEN(x-forwarded-for,0,',')"`

The EXTRACT_TOKEN function is your friend here, this extracts the first ip address from a comma seperated list of addresses in the x-forwarded-for field in an IIS log

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2>logparser -h functions EXTRACT_TOKEN
>
> Functions Syntax
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------->>
>
> EXTRACT_TOKEN( argument , index  [ , separator  ] )>>>>
>
> Examples:
>
> EXTRACT_TOKEN( cs-username, 1, '\' )